# One thread trying to pass data to another thread using Serial Port

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port, dispatcher

For the past 2 days I'm stuck on something but without solution.

I have a class which I wrote and one of its object is "SerialPort" .NET class.
In my MainWindow I created instance of my class called "SerialPortComm", then I send through some functions of mine, commands to the Serial Port, and I receive answers through "DataReceived" event.

But when I trying to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to write my data I have received (successfully), nothing shows on the RichTextBox which I'm trying to write to.

What can caused that, and How I can make it works?

**SerialPortComm.cs** (**EDIT**)

```
public partial class SerialPortComm : UserControl
{
   public SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort();

   public void Open_Port(string comNumber, int baudRate)
   {
      mySerialPort.PortName = comNumber;
      mySerialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
      mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
      mySerialPort.Open();
   }

   public void SetStringDataFromControl(SerialPort sp, string content)
   {
      sp.Write(content + "\n");
   }

   public void SetStringDataFromControl(SerialPort sp, string content)
   {
      sp.Write(content + "\n");
   }

   public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
      SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
      DataRX = sp.ReadExisting(); // Read the data from the Serial Port
      // Print it on the Log
      RichTextBox_logView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
      {
          RichTextBox_logView.AppendText(DataRX);
          RichTextBox_logView.ScrollToEnd();
      });
   }
}
```

**Commands.cs**

```
class Commands
{
   public void SetCommand(SerialPortComm sp, string command)
   {
       sp.SetStringDataFromControl(sp.mySerialPort, command); 
   }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   Commands cmd = new Commands();
   SerialPortComm sp1 = new SerialPortComm();  

   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       sp1.Open_Port("COM6", 115200);
   }

   private async void TextBox_input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
       {
           cmd.SetCommand(sp1, "top");
           cmd.SetCommand(sp1, "run");
           // .... //
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the UI thread blocked, try just invoking the `COM` message via a ThreadPool thread:

```
public void SetCommand(SerialPortComm sp, string command)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
      sp.SetStringDataFromControl(sp.mySerialPort, command); 
 });
}
```

The only issue with this is that these calls are not guaranteed to run and complete in sequence.  You may have to tweak so that the calls are enqueued and consumed in order.  See producer/consumer pattern via the `Concurrent` collections namespace.

http://www.nullskull.com/a/1464/producerconsumer-queue-and-blockingcollection-in-c-40.aspx

Alternatively you could avoid the concurrency issues by just invoking all the commands in their own dedicated (single) thread like this:

```
   if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
   {
     Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
       cmd.SetCommand(sp1, "top");
       cmd.SetCommand(sp1, "run");
       // .... //
     });
   }
```

This is probably an easier implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working for me. Still nothing shows on the RichTextBox.

Comment: does that code hit?  are you logging it to make sure?  is the UI locked/frozen?

Comment: The UI is not locked or frozen. when I'm in debugging mode, I saw that "DataRx" variable contains the correct response answer (string) which I received from the Serial Port (after sending to it some command), but when i'm trying to print it to the Log using the "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()" nothing happens (despite it through OK via that line, and I'm not getting any exception).

Comment: not really... if you are getting the text and you are seeing the code execute and finish when adding the text... then either the color you are setting is making it not visible or there is something else going on that I have no clue of.